# I can't open my apk file

Tags: google-play-store, apk, lucky-patcher

I downloaded an apk from the web that is a paid app in the Play Store, but I can't use the app cause the app knows I downloaded it without paying. I tried it with 2 different apps and these happened:

First worked for a few seconds until it crashed and wouldnt let me open it. When it did open, it asked for a verification through email then crashed again.

Second app isn't in the Play Store anymore, but apk versions still exist. When I downloaded it and opened the app, it asked me to download from the Play Store but it isn't in the Play Store anymore.

I have Lucky Patcher on my tablet too. I was wondering if it could help or is there any alternative. Or its just impossible?

Comment: We do not provide support for hacking paid softwares. You should either buy the software or seek solutions elsewhere where such questions are on-topic. As for the one not available in the Play Store, you should seek the assistance from the developer. Ask them how to make it work. If they decline to extend support, we can't help with it either.

Answer (score 0):

May be these reasons for that..

1. Your app is old or developers stopped publishing
2. That app not available for your country region 
   3.They block apps who download without payment (free Apk)